# app.yaml file: Running 2 Python Files Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google App working and I would like to make it run 2 python files instead of one. Here's my original handlers part of my app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: enwebXML.app
```

Then I wanted to make it run 2 different python files but it just does whatever the first one is doing so it just ignores the seconde file.

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: enwebXML.app
- url: /.*
  script: frwebXML.app
```

I just think that since it's the same url it doesn't go through the second one, I tried to change the urls to 2 sub urls but no chance it doesn't work for some reason, here's the urls I tried with:

```
-url: /en/.*
-url: /fr/.*
```

Since it doesn't work I would like to know if there's something I can do like:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: enwebXML.app
  script: frwebXML.app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app.yaml` pattern url routing works on a 1st match basis: whichever pattern matches first wins and the respective script is invoked - as you observed.

So you need 2 **different** routing patterns to route requests to 2 different scripts. You were on the right track:

```
handlers:
- url: /en/.*
  script: enwebXML.app
- url: /fr/.*
  script: frwebXML.app
```

Of course, you'll need to update accordingly the `app` handler mapping patterns in each of the scripts. Something like this:

- in `enwebXML.app` change `/some_path` to `/en/some_path`
- in `frwebXML.app` change `/some_path` to `/fr/some_path`

Comment: Also do I just copy-paste the description of the first description and replace both with /en/.* and /fr/.*? @Dan Cornilescu